# AttributeError: module 'apscheduler.schedulers.asyncio' has no attribute 'get_event_loop'

Tags: python, python-3.6, python-asyncio, clock, system-clock

I am trying to implement clock process to use in Heroku dyno. I am using Python 3.6. Clock process will run each 3 hours. This is the code:

```py
import os
import sys

import requests
from apscheduler.schedulers import asyncio
from apscheduler.schedulers.asyncio import AsyncIOScheduler
from apscheduler.triggers.interval import IntervalTrigger
from webdriverdownloader import GeckoDriverDownloader

from scraper.common import main


def get_driver():
    return True

def notify(str):
    return True;


if __name__ == '__main__':
    scheduler = AsyncIOScheduler()
    get_driver()
    scheduler.add_job(main, trigger=IntervalTrigger(hours=3))

    scheduler.start()
    # Execution will block here until Ctrl+C (Ctrl+Break on Windows) is pressed.
    try:
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait())
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        pass
```

At first I tried with

```py
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

However, I read that this is not supported in python 3.6, so I changed this statement to `run_until_complete`.

If I run this example, the code prints out:

> AttributeError: module 'apscheduler.schedulers.asyncio' has no attribute 'get_event_loop'

Does anyone know why this error occurs? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `run_forever` has been available since asyncio was added in Python 3.4. You might be confusing it with `asyncio.run` which was added in 3.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not importing the `asyncio` module from the standard library but the `asyncio` module in the `apscheduler` library. You can see that by visiting the link [here](https://github.com/agronholm/apscheduler/blob/master/apscheduler/schedulers/asyncio.py).

There are only two things you can import from that namespace:

1. `run_in_event_loop`
2. `AsyncIOScheduler`

If you need to use the low-level `asyncio` API just import `asyncio` directly from the standard library.